# Tableau Correlated Subquery?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau and connecting to my data source using SQL server. My data tables are comprised of SQL views which have been created. I have two main views called Visits and Items.

The visits table comprises of a persons visit to a particular place such as a restaurant or a fast food establishment. The Items table shows us the different menu items that was ordered from that visit. So a visit can have many menu items which are associated with it.

In my SQL views I have been adding variables such as:

```
isnull((SELECT
    TOP 1 
        CASE
            WHEN Gen_Menu_Label_ENG in ('Any gelato','Any ice cream','Any milkshake','Hard ice cream',
            'Other Ice Cream / Frozen Yoghurt / Gelato','Soft serve ice cream') THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM Items_Data ID 
WHERE ID.RESP_ID = TBV.RESP_ID
and ID.OCCASION_ID = TBV.OCCASION_ID
and ID.BRANDVISIT_ID = TBV.BRANDVISIT_ID),'') as IceCreamFlag,
```

Where I create the IceCreamFlag variable in my SQL and then connect to my data source in SQL.

What I'm trying to do is create my IceCreamFlag variable in Tableau but I'm having trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IN will soon be supported in Tableau, but for now you can do something like:

CASE [Gen_Menu_Label_ENG]
WHEN 'Any gelato' THEN 1
WHEN 'Any ice cream' THEN 1
...
ELSE 0
END

You will be able to manipulate as required within the Tableau worksheets, using MAX, WINDOW_MAX, FIXED{MAX}, etc